# absolute value definition.

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I'm reading my pre-calc book and their definition of absolute values is driving me bonkers.  They keep saying that |x| = -x and also -x = |x| = c.  I can't figure out how to rationalize |x| = -x.  In my mind if x = -5 then |-5| equals 5.  BUT -5 can not equal 5 so how can they say |x| = -x?

Below is from from the book

The `Equality Properties' can be proved
using Definition 2.4 and by looking at the cases when x >= 0, in which case |x| = x, or when x < 0, in which case |x| = -x. For example, if c > 0, and |x| = c, then if x >= 0, we have x = |j| = c. If, on the other hand, x < 0, then -x = |x| = c, so x = -c.

Comment: |x|=-x when x is negative. |x|=x when x is positive.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

$$
\left|-5\right|=-\left(-5\right)=5
$$

The $x$ is negative too, in fact if $x<0$
$$
\left|x\right|=-x
$$
and if $x \geq 0$
$$
\left|x\right|=x
$$

Answer (score 1):

Note that in general the definition is

$$\left| f(x) \right| = 
\begin{cases}
   f(x) \hspace{1cm} f(x) \geq 0 \\\\ -f(x)  \hspace{0.7cm} f(x) < 0
\end{cases}$$

In the particular case of f(x)=x it can be useful visualize the definition by the following graph

[image]